# Hide current div and show another among multiple divs with same class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs with same classes, they go like this:

```
            <div class="item even">
                <div class="image-normal">
                    <a title="VORTEILE" href=""><img width="120" height="141" border="0" alt="" src="uploads/pics/vorteile.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="image-hover">
                    <a title="VORTEILE" href=""><img width="120" height="141" border="0" alt="" src="uploads/pics/vorteile_hover.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <span>VORTEILE</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Also a little css to hide 2 divs initially:

```
.two-columns-gravity-left .column-right div.image-hover {
    display: none;
}

.two-columns-gravity-left .column-right div.tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

I want when I hover over `.image-normal` to hide that specific div and show / fade in `image-hover` and `.tooltip`, and on mouseout for reverse to happen.

I tried with the following but it keeps on blinking (changing realy fast) while mouse is over the div, it is acting like it is continously doing mouseover and mouseout.

js:

```
$('div.image-normal').hover(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings().show();
}, function() {
    $(this).show().sibling().hide();
});
```

Comment: when you hide the DIV, you are firing the out handler of same DIV

Comment: you can add a class to the parent (.item) on hover and use css for the hide/show

Comment: @wolf, so how to remedy this? huangism - example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by binding hover on the parent .item div

http://jsfiddle.net/HDv4q/

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('current');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});
```

Then do the hide/show with css

```
.item.current div.image-normal {
    display: none;
}
.two-columns-gravity-left .column-right .item.current div.image-hover,
.two-columns-gravity-left .column-right .item.current div.tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

what's happening in your original code is that when you hover image-normal, it hides and the other stuff appears. But when image-normal hides itself, it also triggers the mouseout event (unhovered since it is hidden), which is why you get the constant flickering because it is constantly hover/unhover

Comment: this is good, but it keeps changing as I move mouse around the div. It should stay untill mouseout.

Comment: I just updated the answer, I had the hover binding on the wrong item